# Sorting a large amount of data excel

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting

I need to sort through a large amount of data in multiple 600,000 row csv files of a test I've just conducted.

This is a snippet.

[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF4mH.png)

Effectively what I'm after is to pick the largest number from column C and and it's correspond row in column B for each test run.

E.g. I ran "big test" first the largest number in column c is 42.59797 and it's corresponding row is  2045.591 up until small test begins. Then pick the biggest number in column C for "small test" which will be 40.12216 and it's corresponding row will be -2106.67 and repeat all the way down the column. Also the data extracted must be in the order it was extracted in.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you maybe reword this in a clearer way. You say you're looking for the largest number in column C but then you say you repeat this down the column. If you're having to repeat it then you can't be using the whole column, so what's the range for each repeat?

Comment: Yes sorry, I will need to repeat this down the column, the range is 35-50 for each test until the next one e.g. "big test" pick the largest number in that range until "small test" then repeat throughout the column. Hope this clears up any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in 3 columns to the right (columns F to H)

F2 formula is: `=ROW()-H2`

G2 (array) formula is: `{=MIN(IF($H$2:$H$30=H2,$F$2:$F$30))+H2}` *adjust 30 so its the end of your range*

H2 (array) formula is: `{=IFERROR(MATCH(IF(D2="Big Test","Small Test","Big Test"),$D2:$D$30,0)+ROW()-1,MAX(ROW($D2:$D$30))+1)-1}` *again adjust 30 to suit*

Your associated torque for the max pull out for that particular cycle operation is: `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(G2,3)&":"&ADDRESS(H2,3))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(G2,3)&":"&ADDRESS(H2,3)),0)+G2-1,2)),0,0)`

[image: example]

Comment: Hi Tim thank you very much for your input, just another quick question if I wanted the associated pull out in column K, would I just have to edit the code you've posted slightly to suit? Thanks.

Comment: That'd be the MAX part of the previous formula. That finds the pull out and then gets the associated torque. As you're new on the site you might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you feel I've answered your question sufficiently.